# Compile file which includes ext2fs.h

Tags: c, ext2

So I am writing a C file which includes /extfs/ext2fs.h. I am trying to call the function ext2fs_open(). I can clearly see that the header file ext2fs.h has that particular function. In fact, if I pass in the incorrect number of arguments, it even corrects me. However it does not compile, always giving me a "undefined reference" error. This problem lies with all the methods defined in the header file. How am I supposed to compile this file? Is there some library I need to link to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to link to [libext2fs](http://koeritz.org/docs/e2fslibs/html-info/libext2fs_1.html), yes...

```
gcc -I/dir/containing/ext2fs.h -lext2fs your_source.c -o app
```

Comment: Thankyou. I am still a little confused though. When you say app, you mean the executable file name I would want it to be right? If so, I couldn't run the command with the app. For instance my source code is myfile.c. I did: gcc -I/ext2fs/ext2fs.h -lext2fs myfile.c myfile -- but that did not work. I removed the myfile from the back and it compiled. However, I got an a.out file, what exactly is this? I want an executable file to run.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Updated answer. You need to use `-o myfile`. Also, put the full path to the *directory* in which the file `ext2fs.h` resides after the `-I` parameter, not the full path to the *file*.